# Rails LDAP and Devise Authentication automatically from Active Directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ldap

I am trying to authenticate users from Active Directory using devise and ldap in Rails . 
I am successful in authenticating from Login Credentials which users enter.
But once user is authenticated his credentials will be saved in session.
I do not want users to login using credentials. But the application 
should detect Domain once user logs into windows and use Windows authentication 
if that Domain is present in Active Directory.

I followed this : http://everything-ruby.blogspot.in/2011/04/installing-windows-server-2008-ee-with_13.html and works fine.

Can anyone guide me in right path to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I am using thses gems **rails 4.1.4**,  **devise**, **devise_ldap_authenticatable**

Answer (score 0):

Kind of an old post but others may be interested:
It sounds to me that what you're trying to achieve is single sign-on.  If so then you probably want to look into CAS (Central Authentication Services) instead. AD supports this and it's pretty easy in Rails as well.